# how to access values present in external XML file?

Tags: android

I have an xml file called names.xml, that contains the following

```
    <names type="xyz" order_groups="true">
        <group landscape_position="left">
            <box type="abc"/>
        </group>
        <group landscape_position="right" order_alphabetical="true">
            <box type="cc"/>
            <box type="bb"/>
            <box type="aa"/>
            <box type="ee"/>
        </group>            
    </names>
```

I want to access these values into my code. Can anyone say Where can i include this code in my project ?? i.e .,is it in res,assets or any other folders. And how can i access the values present inside this xml file into my code. Please help me out in this.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If this is your own XML you can parse it using [SAX parser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/package-summary.html)

To read the XML file in assets folder look here at [Asset Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html)